# Tensorflow: Implementing new loss function returns a "ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable"

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient, valueerror, loss-function

I need to implement a new loss function for my deep network which is the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python import confusion_matrix
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops

def gms_loss(targets=None, logits=None, name=None):
    #Shape checking
    try:
        targets.get_shape().merge_with(logits.get_shape())
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("logits and targets must have the same shape (%s vs %s)"
                         % (logits.get_shape(), targets.get_shape()))
    #Compute the confusion matrix
    predictions=tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    cm=confusion_matrix(tf.argmax(targets,1),tf.argmax(predictions,1),3)

    def compute_sensitivities(name):
        """Compute the sensitivity per class via the confusion matrix."""
        per_row_sum = math_ops.to_float(math_ops.reduce_sum(cm, 1))
        cm_diag = math_ops.to_float(array_ops.diag_part(cm))
        denominator = per_row_sum

        # If the value of the denominator is 0, set it to 1 to avoid
        # zero division.
        denominator = array_ops.where(
            math_ops.greater(denominator, 0), denominator,
            array_ops.ones_like(denominator))

        accuracies = math_ops.div(cm_diag, denominator)
        return accuracies

    gms = math_ops.reduce_prod(compute_sensitivities('sensitivities'))
    return gms
```

Here is the calling from the graph code:

```
test=gms_loss(targets=y,logits=pred)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(test)
```

and finally, the already known error:

```
"ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables..."
```

I'm not able to find the problem, if I use softmax_cross_entropy, it works (but is not able to optimize properly, thats why I need the new loss function)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the `tf.argmax()` function is not differentiable. Therefore, the optimizer will fail to calculate the gradient of the loss function with respect to your predictions and targets. I don't know of a way to handle this with the argmax function, so I would recommend to avoid non-differentiable functions.

Comment: You are right, forget about it, GMS is just not derivable... Thanks for your time.

Comment: @DarkHawk I am running into a similar issue when trying to create a custom cost/loss function. I was using argmax to figure out the confusion matrix and NOT penalize False Negatives as much as False Positives. Did you ever come up with a solution to your problem? Do you mind sharing? Thanks!

Comment: @mschmidt42 Assuming that the positive (signal) index is 0 and all other indices are negative (background), you could use something like `w = s(y)[:,0] * (1 - y'[:,0]) + K * (1 - s(y)[:,0]) * y'[:, 0], where y is the network output, s(y) is the softmax of the network output, and y' are the true labels. This produces large errors for false positives (first part of the sum) and false negatives (second part). There is no `argmax` in there, so it also yields an error for correct predictions, but it is differentiable. You can tune the relative weighting of the parts by increasing or decreasing K.

Comment: @mschmidt42 Just add this loss `w` to the existing cross entropy loss function, or replace it by `w`.